# What is a Spring "stereotype"?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, stereotype

On a SpringSource blog entry, the following sentence references a *stereotype*.

> Because `@Controller` is a specialization of Spring's `@Component` 
>   Stereotype annotation, the class will automatically be detected by the
>   Spring container as part of the container's component scanning
>   process, creating a bean definition and allowing instances to be
>   dependency  injected like any other Spring-managed component.

What does this usage of the word stereotype reference?  Is this a technical Spring term?  Or is stereotype just used in a general sense?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html) says a bit about it.

> Annotations denoting the roles of types or methods in the overall architecture (at a conceptual, rather than implementation, level).

The noun definition of `stereotype` from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stereotype) says this:

> something conforming to a fixed or general pattern; especially : a standardized mental picture that is held in common by members of a group and that represents an oversimplified opinion, prejudiced attitude, or uncritical judgment

It seems that it is for suggesting a role of particular class that is being annotated.  This seems to make sense because it is often recommended that you  annotate your Controller classes with `@Controller`, Service classes with `@Service`, and so on.

In addition to the obvious component-scanning functionality, Spring suggests that they make nice point-cut demarcations for your AOP needs.

Comment: I am up voting this answer because when I am trying to understand a new concept how these technical term relates with underlying concept helps me to digest.Stereotype is also exists in UML which is used for creating reusable & extensible domain component from an existing meta class as a template.

Answer (score 14):

> Is this a technical Spring term? Or is stereotype just used in a general sense?

I think Spring borrow the term Stereotype from the real world to Spring's technical term.

From American English dictionary:

> (noun) a widely held but fixed and oversimplified image or idea of a particular type of person or thing.

In real world we know some stereotype, for example: American like to drink coffee. British like to drink tea. Of course, its not true for all American or British. Its just an oversimplification of American or British people.

Using stereotype help us making faster decision. When your American friends comes over, instead of asking them "What would you like to drink?" and wait for their response. You can assume that they want a coffee.

In Spring, stereotype help us to simplify object creation. You don't need to define the relationship between `Type`, because you make stereotype of the `Type`.

Note: [`Type` in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html). Class is a `Type`.

---

Say we have these classes:

```
public abstract class Friend {

    public abstract String favoriteDrink();
}

public class American extends Friend {

    @Override
    public String favoriteDrink() {
        return "Coffee";
    }
}
```

**Without Stereotype**

You have to define the relationship between Friend and American (Friend is-an American) in a Configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class YourAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Friend defineFriend() {
        return new American();
    }
}
```

So, in the test you can verify that:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class YourAppTest {

    @Autowired
    private Friend friend;

    @Test
    public void drinkTest() {
        assertEquals(friend.favoriteDrink(), "Coffee");
    }
}
```

**With Stereotype**

Stereotype tell Spring that all Friend is an American, directly on the Class declaration.

```
@Component
public class American extends Friend {

    @Override
    public String favoriteDrink() {
        return "Coffee";
    }
}
```

If your classes encounter a Friend class, it will assume its an American. It's a one-to-one relationship between Friend and American.

This is very useful if you want your class to behave that way. You don't need to define a Bean to your Configuration file. (You don't even need a Configuration file). Spring will automatically create a Bean from that Stereotype.

---

That is why the Component, Repository, Service, and Controller annotations belong to Stereotype package.
Spring doesn't care much about the detail of your class, from Spring perspective your Classes are either `Repository`, `Service`, and `Controller`, if it doesn't belong to any of that, then its a `Component`.

Spring just making **oversimplification** of your Classes. Hence, the name Stereotype.

Comment: Super!!.. @aldok